# Remove "dtype" and "object" from list output

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function that is supposed to return some values based on a dataframe, on certain conditions.

```
def myFun(declaration, policynumber, ID):
    tempvar = df.loc[(df['Moneyamount'] == 70) & (df['ID'] == ID) & (df['Nr deklaracji'] == declaration) & (df['Nr Polisy'] == policynumber)]
    if len(tempvar) == 1:
        info = [declaration, 'YES', ID, tempvar['Birthdate'], tempvar['City'], tempvar['Street'], tempvar['Housenumber']]
    elif len(tempvar) == 0:
        info = [declaration, 'NO', ID, tempvar['Birthdate'], tempvar['City'], tempvar['Street'], tempvar['Housenumber']]
    return(info)
```

Everything works, except the fact that the outcome is like this:

```
[90052,
 'YES',
 58041991951,
 0    19-04-58
 Name: Birthdate, dtype: object,
 0    Warsaw
 Name: City, dtype: object,
 0    Bluestreet
 Name: Street, dtype: object,
 0    6
 Name: Housenumber, dtype: object]
```

My task however is not only for that function to work, but also to print the outcome to .json. Problem is however, when I try to print this into a .json, it keeps the "0, Name:, dtype: object" part, and I'd like to get rid of that.

I've looked through stack and google in general, but the usual workarounds were in a situation where an entire list was of the same datatype.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I found a workaround:

I added

.tolist()[0]

after each of the values that refers to the dataframe, like this

```
    info = [declaration, 'NO', ID, tempvar['Birthdate'].tolist()[0], tempvar['City'].tolist()[0], tempvar['Street'].tolist()[0], tempvar['Housenumber'].tolist()[0]]
```

This allowed me to receive a neat .json format. It's not the best possible solution, but it works for me here. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Could you please append the code to your question

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are directly taking the desired column from filtered data like:

`df[df['column_name']==value][column_name]`

Try:

`df[df['column_name']==value][column_name].values.tolist()`